# Tool to post topics and vote and comment, with a search feature to show if a similar topic already exists

Tags: survey, crowdsourcing, voting

I need a tool with reddit-like voting and sort-based-on-votes features, but also with a search option before someone posts a new thread to minimize number of duplicate topics. I have looked at kiunei and other google moderator replacements and they are too narrow focusing on public events etc. Is there any other tool that you know of that I should be looking at before starting to build one from scratch?

Comment: You mean like the stackexchange sites?

Comment: Well yes some modifications will be needed since I don't want a Q&A style but it would be a nice starting point. b ut I think SE software is not open source?

Comment: Something similar to https://userecho.com/ might be what youre looking for. i've seen it used as a way for users of an app ([example](https://feedback.textasticapp.com/)) to post and vote on feedback